# Basic probability: conditioning equations

Tags: probability, problem-solving, conditional-probability

I'm quite new to probability and I'm quite confused by a certain "operation" that is performed in my lecture notes. It's the operation of conditioning both sides of an equation on a certain event. For example, in my notes I have:

$$P(A\cap B)=P(A)P(B).$$

By conditioning on $C$ we obtain:

$$P(A\cap B\mid C)=P(A\mid C)P(B\mid C).$$

But how do we know that we can use this kind of conditioning on a particular equation? I can think of many examples when such conditioning would lead to errors. For example, rolling a die:

If we define:

> $A$ as getting either $1$ or $2$,
> $B$ as getting either $5$ or $6,$
> and $C$ as getting $4$ of more, then it's true that:

$$P(A)=P(B).$$

But:

$$P(A\mid C)\neq P(B\mid C).$$

Could anyone help me understand this problem? Thank you in advance.

Comment: No, the “conditioning” step you initially give is not valid. Just because two events are independent does not mean they are conditionally independent given a third event.

Comment: Valid operations are using the definition of conditional probability, using the axioms, and using consequences of these such as the law of total probability. You can also use basic substitution, for example if events $A$ and $B$ are the same, so that $A=B$, then by basic substitution we have $P[A]=P[B]$ and also $P[A|C]=P[B|C]$.

Comment: May be you think about "inherited" probability? For given $C, P(C)>0$ we can consider new probability space with events for each $A \subset \Omega$  taking as $A \cap C$.